# Scraping pseudo-elements from a website with XPath

Tags: html, css, xpath, scrapy

I want to extract data from a website, but it seems that the elements that I want to extract are not "accessible".I also discovered they seem to be pseudo-elements. I can se that their tags are marked with a # before in my web-inspector.

Moreover, while using XPath I can't extract the text I want to access. Their is a point in the CSS "cascade tree" when I can't extract the content of a tag, you can see it below. 
Here I can extract information up to the tag 'content fond'. But when I ask for the tag "fos_comment_thread" which is the tag just below, the return is empty. And it is especially this tag which is a pseudo-element, and the following behind. However the text I want to access is even more deeper in this part of the CSS tree...

Input

```
reponse.xpath=('//div[class@='row']/div[@class='span9 forum']/div[class@='content fond'].extract()
```

Output

```
['<div id="foc_comment_thread"<div>']
```

Input

```
reponse.xpath=('//div[class@='row']/div[@class='span9 forum']/div[class@='content fond']/div[id@='fos_comment_thread'].extract()
```

Output
    []

I don't understand why I can't extract, I think it is due to the fact that the rest of my tags are pseudo-elements,but I haven't found a solution to solve the problem...

Comment: Psuedo-elements are not in the DOM, they are **styling** and so probably can't be selected as you suggest.

Comment: you should try `resposne.css("#fos_comment_thread *").extract()`

Comment: that returns me to an empty list as the element doesn't existed

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is to not using your web-inspector tool and look at the raw HTML of the website.

Web inspectors take into account the transformations made by Javascript and may show you an update HTML after Javascript execution, that scrapy obviously can't see.

Comment: as @Guillaume said, I will add that if you wanna look for an element in the rendered javascript html consider using "Splash" link: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash